# How to update object property changes in a transaction?

Tags: python, oop, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

I am designing an application where we perform operations on customer records, eg we can update their balance, add items they buy or give them offers etc. I want each operation to be atomic in nature.

The application is written in Python but the problem that I'm trying to solve is language agnostic.

Now I have multiple async functions which are running concurrently and can update the customer record. But I only want to update the customer record if everything works correctly and no exceptions are thrown. And revert back if an exception is thrown.

To ensure only one function can update a customer, I have a lock on the customer record that only one async functiom can acquire at the moment. The customer records are mutable types so they can be updated by the functions.

```
class Customer:
  def __init__(self, name, balance, items):
     self.name = name
     self.balance = balance
     self.items = items
     self.lock = asyncio.Lock()


class Handler:

   async def handle(customer, type, data):

      async with customer.lock:
        try:
         #all functions that update customer properties
          
          if type == 'updatebalance' : 
             UpdateCustomerBalance(customer, data)
          else:
             UpdateCustomerItems(customer, data) 

        except Exception as ex:
          #how do I revert customer changes? 
          pass
```

In the code above, I have a customer class. It has few properties and a lock.

Whenever handler is called, it acquires the customer's lock. It calls other functions that take the data and update customer properties.

Customer is a reference type and is mutated by these functions eg one function can update the balance. If an exception is caught then I want to revert the changes.

When I run call handle multiple times asynchronously, I want to ensure the same customer record is sent to the functions so that the successful changes are saved in the customer record and we don't lose the changes eg one handle call can add item, the second can remove that item.

So in short, I want a transaction mechanism. Is this possible to do? Should I deep clone the customer object within try and pass that to the functions? But then I will have to manually update the changed properties so that the next call works on the updated object.

What's the right way to implement a transaction?

Comment: The "Right Way" to implement transactions, wherever possible, is not to. Transactions have tricky edge cases, so re-using someone else's work is better if you can swing it. Can you possibly recast your problem as a database problem and work with database operations instead of object mutations?

Comment: If you don't `await` anything inside the `async with` block, you don't need any locking because everything will be atomic to begin with. Restoring the changes performed on arbitrary objects with an exception being raised anywhere inbetween is an extremely hard problem. As the previous comment says, don't try to implement it yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain the locking part? The list of customer records are stored in a dictionary which I periodically persist in the database. I have multiple async tasks running the background that listen to events and perform operations on the customer. Some of these actions buy products from external websites eg amazon. None of these functions do await as I await the handle function from outside. Are you saying I don't need a lock? Plus I can't use a database after every operation as its a high traffic app

Comment: Also the lock ensures that the handle function is called in the right order eg if I get two handle requests, one to add money in the balance of the customer and one to remove the customer balance then I won't remove the balance first before adding it. Hence my understanding was that when the handle couroutine is called asynchronously via asyncio.create_task then the lock will provide ordering too

Comment: *Are you saying I don't need a lock?* - yes, I am saying that if you don't await anything, you don't need a lock because it won't accomplish anything. Asyncio multitasking is cooperative, and if you don't await, there is no way to switch to a different task, so a lock is superfluous. As for ordering, the lock is fair and will respect the order in which acquiring it was attempted, but you'll get the same effect without the lock because asyncio cannot run two things at once. When thinking about this, always keep in mind that asyncio is **single-threaded**.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there a transaction library that you recommend. Or any thing that didn't involve database

Comment: I don't know of one, but based on the stated requirements, you shouldn't need one, either. As long as you make changes to the data model between awaits (or use locks if you do have awaits during critical sections), the changes will be effectively atomic and you should be fine.

Comment: Not really. Consider this... There are two functions to be called. what happens when I update a property of a customer in one function and the second function throws an exception, the handler will catch it but the customer object is already updated now so the next handle call will see the updated object whereas I should revert the changes

Comment: You didn't use "@" to mention me, so I wasn't notified about this comment. My remark applied only to use of an async lock to get atomicity, which is unnecessary between awaits. Rolling back an object in case of exception is a different problem, orthogonal to "async safety".

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Customer` objects immutable and change the state by substitution of an entire object. This approach does not require any transactions, since all changes will be reduced to a single substitution.

e.g.

```py
customer_store = {}

class Handler:

    async def handle(self, customer, type, data):
        # create new customer for any updates 
        current_customer = customer_store[customer.key]
        if type == 'updatebalance': 
            new_customer = UpdateCustomerBalance(current_customer, data)
        else:
            new_customer = UpdateCustomerItems(current_customer, data) 
        # substitution             
        customer_store[customer.key] = new_customer
```

Also `handle` does not need a `Lock` until it is awaiting for something.

Comment: If I use await within the function and if my customer is a mutable reference type then won't there be just one version of the customer in all tasks? I'm struggling with await and locks

Comment: Also with your design, the next call to handle which is already in the queue will lose the changes this handle call will make

Comment: _won't there be just one version of the customer in all tasks?_ - Sorry, question is not clear for me. What do you mean by _one version of the customer_? If you mean the same Customer object, then answer is No, they may be different objects

Comment: If you use await within the function, then you will have to lock a Customer object, because await may switch execution to another task that may try to access the same Customer object

Comment: _the next call to handle which is already in the queue will lose the changes_. It happens if you assume concurrent execution of `handle`. In this case, you can take a Customer object from `customer_store` inside the function. I updated the answer

Comment: Some of the functions are from a library that I can't update hence I'll have to write a wrapper for each function. What about getting customer from store, deep cloning the customer object and then passing it to the functions and later updating the store  before releasing the lock (I do need to await inside functions too)

Comment: It will work too, since changes of state (store in this case) will be reduced to a single substitution